# Store Polygon points to sqlite database

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

In my app I create fields on the map by using polygons.The polygons are created by the user by clicking on the map and creating points/markers and the clicking a button to create the polygon.
Now I want these fields/polygons to be stored on my SQLite database but the points are given in lat/lng data type.

One way I thought of doing this is by storing the string of the *polygon.getPoints()* function:

```
Polygon p;
String latlng = p.getPoints().toString();
```

The output of latlng is:

```
[lat/lng: (-3.987413925092502,-18.76223847270012), lat/lng: (-4.878691546616136,-2.84572284668684), lat/lng: (-7.610723424687183,-11.666696257889273), lat/lng: (-3.987413925092502,-18.76223847270012)]
```

And then when retrieving it from the database convert all the points by first removing all the unnecessary text from the string using *replaceAll()* and then putting every single point on the list and then again converting them to lat/lng.

It seems a little bit like overkill is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why not store latitude and longitude in separate columns for each point? I'd probably also create a table to store the polygons or the fields and keep a reference to that in each point that is part of it - along with an order column for each point so you get the right sequence for the polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Pattern LAT_LNG = Pattern.compile("([-\\d.]+),([-\\d.]+)");
String latlng = "[lat/lng: (-3.987413925092502,-18.76223847270012),"
    + "lat/lng: (-4.878691546616136,-2.84572284668684),"
    + "lat/lng: (-7.610723424687183,-11.666696257889273),"
    + "lat/lng: (-3.987413925092502,-18.76223847270012)]";
Matcher matcher = LAT_LNG.matcher(latlng);
while (matcher.find()) {
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("lat=" + lat + " lng=" + lng);
}
```

output:

```
lat=-3.987413925092502 lng=-18.76223847270012
lat=-4.878691546616136 lng=-2.84572284668684
lat=-7.610723424687183 lng=-11.666696257889273
lat=-3.987413925092502 lng=-18.76223847270012
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way to get the lat/lng individually from the String.